# Unable to connect to OpenId Provider

Tags: asp.net, openid, dotnetopenauth

When I run in visual studio I am able to connect to openid provider, But if I host app in IIS ,I am not able to connect to openid provider. (I am getting error at CreateRequest)

Please let me know what settings has to be done in IIS so that I can connect to the Openid Provider. Below is the error I am getting

> [InvalidOperationException: Sequence
>   contains no elements]
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.First(IEnumerable`1
>   source) +336
>   DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdRelyingParty.CreateRequest(Identifier
>   userSuppliedIdentifier)
>
> [ProtocolException: No OpenID endpoint
>   found.]
>   DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdRelyingParty.CreateRequest(Identifier
>   userSuppliedIdentifier)

Answer (score 2):

This is usually a firewall issue.  That may not apply to you if your IIS and VS are on the same machine, but it's something that you may consider.

Otherwise the best way to find out why it failed is to [activate logging](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/loggingdebugging-dotnetopenauth-with-log4net/) and set a verbose logging setting.  You could alternatively just install one of the shipping OpenID RP samples to your IIS, as they have a built-in TracePage.aspx file that will display verbose logging to you.  If the samples also fail, the logs should tell you why.  If the samples *don't* fail, then that will tell you something about your web site as well, and logging on your site will hopefully help further.

Please also check out ["No OpenID endpoint found" on Azure Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969426/no-openid-endpoint-found-on-azure-website/11112383#11112383) as this may be a duplicate question.

Comment: +1 Thank you. Indeed it was a firewall issue for me.