# "No OpenID endpoint found" on Azure Website

Tags: azure, dotnetopenauth, azure-web-app-service

I have a strange issue with a MVC 3 app running as an Azure Website. I have had issues with Azure in the past, but the new Website concept works almost perfectly, except for this:

```
DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException: No OpenID endpoint found.
```

This only happens with Google, only on Azure. Running locally it works fine, running on AppHarbor it works fine, but on Azure every attempt to use Google for OpenID login will result in a server error due to that exception (tracked using Airbrake).

See for yourself, try logging in with Google on [my website](http://versulo.azurewebsites.net) and if you immediately get a server error page it means DNOA is throwing up. All other login methods work fine, including Yahoo and AOL which are also OpenID.

P.S.: Don't try it too many times though, AirBrake will happily spam my email address :<

Comment: Would you please try to add OAuth logging to your application as described here to get more info why it is failing on Windows Azure http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/help/loggingdebugging-dotnetopenauth-with-log4net/

Comment: @AvkashChauhan I tried using Glimpse but the DNOA tab is inactive, suggesting that nothing is being logged.

Comment: @AndrewArnott I tried using log4net directly, nothing is being logged apparently.

Comment: I am not familiar with DotNetOpenAuth. But I suggest you to use Windows Azure ACS. It also supports Google as an identity provider, and it works fine in Windows Azure.

Comment: @MingXu-MSFT, wouldn't that require 1) using cloud services instead of websites, 2) rewriting the whole auth code, 3) locking myself to Azure exclusively. And would that even run locally? The emulator isn't... that great, deployment to cloud services is really slow, etc. No thanks.

Comment: @MirceaChirea I'm having the exact same problem but it only occurs the first time, once per app start, it seems.  Also I'm only using google at the moment so IDK if anything else is causing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this code to your web site *before* calling `OpenIdRelyingParty.CreateRequest`:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

In some Azure configurations this has been shown to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly for me. Do you have a more in-depth explanation into why this is necessary?

Comment: It seems that those on the new Azure preview web hosting service are running their sites in a new environment/sandbox, where the default SSL settings are non-standard.  When sending an HTTP request to Google, SSL v3 is (apparently) used and the default configuration, whatever it is, can't adjust to it without a little help.  The Azure folks are working on the problem so that it works by default in the future.

Comment: This answer fixed the problem for accessing Google APIs. However, I am still having the same problem with accessing Exchange Web Services even with this workaround implemented.

Answer (score -1):

I had this function in global.asax:

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

After removing this line, all works perfectly.

I've added some areas in my app, this function was added automatically by VS2012.