# Azure WebSites and Google Api

Tags: azure, google-api, azure-web-app-service

I've been playing around with azure websites. I'm using some google api but it seems that once deployed on Azure WebSites a problem appears when requesting Google Apis :

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

I'm not sure where it does come from since I can browse my websites using HTTPS, maybe it's from IIS ARR plugin?

Edit
I'm adding some code

@mcollier I'm using the WebClient to make the call. It will fail on downloading the result (http get request)

```
  try
  {
     WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

     string request = string.Format("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=intitle:{0}&fields=items(volumeInfo)&maxResults=1&printType=books&key={1}", infos.Value, ConfigurationHelper.GoogleKey);
     content = webClient.DownloadString(request);
   }               
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       throw new Exception("content from WebClient : " + content, ex);
       // Log.
   }
```

Comment: Can you post a little more information?  Windows Azure Web Sites shouldn't prohibit you from accessing any other web service.  Is the Google API just a regular HTTP/HTTPS GET request?

Comment: Does this work from the Windows Azure Emulator on your Dev machine?

Comment: @user728584 hello, since azure websites is a regular web site it doesn't require all the azure sdk stuff to run on. The calls work on my local machine.

Comment: Duplicate of this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969426/no-openid-endpoint-found-on-azure-website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding this to your Application_Start in Global.asax.cs should solve your problem:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

Comment: Actually I've tried this but I didn't make the call at the right place. Thanks! It works now

Comment: Note this problem impacts Exchange Web Services API as well and the work around DOES NOT fix that case. At least for me.