# Initial "No OpenID Endpoint Found" on Windows Azure

Tags: azure, openid, dotnetopenauth

I've looked at the various questions on this topic but none of them QUITE fit the problem I'm having.

I've developed an MVC4 app which utilizes DNOA to call into a particular provider (Intuit). All worked perfectly on my local IIS (testing) but when I deployed to Windows Azure I get the proverbial wonderful "strange, intermittent" behavior. Specifically, 99% of the time, the initial sign-in request results in the "No OpenID Endpoint Found" error; however, SUBSEQUENT sign-ins go through without a hitch.

I've added the code referred to here: [ServiceManagerCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969426/no-openid-endpoint-found-on-azure-website), to no avail. I've checked and the OpenID URL is correct. I've also attempted to add log4net to see what might be occurring but have been unable to do this correctly, some other answers seem to suggest this returns nothing anyway. I've also asked Intuit but, so far, no responses.

Again, if this wasn't occurring on just the first attempt then there would be numerous relevant posts but with this peculiar behavior I am wary of wasting inordinate amounts of time on a wild goose chase.

Any suggestions, however slight, would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Which Azure service are you hosting with?  The preview "web site" multi-tenant hosting, or the more stable web role?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with OpenID. Is the OpenID sign in service hosted by you in Windows Azure as well? Please make sure the sign in service has started without any problems, one suggestion is to check the federation configuration. Most federation providers require you to configure the realm and return URL. If they’re not properly configured, the application won’t work.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: Well I'm a newbie with OpenID, but no, while there are many OpenID providers (e.g. Google), the particular one I'm referring to is  Intuit. They host on their servers. My app is designed for use with Quickbooks and I will be using Intuit's OpenID exclusively to authorize users.As I mentioned, I have a query in with their tech guys about this but haven't heard back.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that your Azure relying party works reliably *after* the first failed attempt, perhaps you can workaround it by having your app_start event in your Azure web role call DotNetOpenAuth's `OpenIdRelyingParty.CreateRequest` method, not doing anything with its result, just to 'prime the pump'?

Comment: Well, that certainly is an option. If all else fails I may have to do it if I can't find the real reason. I'm toying with the idea that this is a timing issue (there was one SO post in a similar thread that mentioned such a possibility) so I'll look into it. Thanks.

Comment: How did you end solving that issue? I'm having this exact problem with  MVC4's DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet. Initial request fails, others do well.

Comment: same issue here... did you manage to resolve issue without application startup dummy request workaround?