# asp.net MVC 4 External Login Provider - 'No OpenID endpoint found' (google)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth, openid, asp.net-4.5

I'm learning MVC 4 (Visual Studio Express 2012) and trying to use the new templates that have baked in openId/OAuth external login support.  I've been following [this tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/15/oauth-openid-support-for-webforms-mvc-and-webpages.aspx)

All I've done so far is create a new MVC 4 internet application with Forms Authentication, and uncommented the `OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterGoogleClient();` line in the `AuthConfig.cs` file.

Changing one line of code from a stock template seems like it should be pretty easy, but when I run the project, I get a "No OpenID endpoint found" exception when I click on the google button.

Keep in mind I have no experience trying to do anything with OAuth/OpenID before.

Does this perhaps have something to do with the fact that I'm running it off localhost on my dev machine?  Or some other environment variable like our corporate proxy server/firewall?

I got the impression from [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/security/enabling-login-from-external-sites-in-an-aspnet-web-pages-site) that you can test this from localhost (at least for Google).

Or is there a different reason for that error?

Before answering, be aware that I do not want to write custom code to get this working. I want to use the stock template.

---

## UPDATE

I tried it at home, and it works no problem on local host.  It must have something to do with the network environment at my workplace.  Either the firewall or proxy probably.   I'd still love to get this working at work though if anyone has any suggestions...

Comment: no endpoint found means, in general, that an attempt to call a web service or api was made, but no endpoint binding for that service exists in the web.config file.

Comment: Are you deploying to Windows Azure?  If so this may be your fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969426/no-openid-endpoint-found-on-azure-website

Answer (score 1):

You're following the tutorial correctly, as far as I can see, but it seems a little sketchy on using Google. This has more detail: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/09/12/integrate-openauth-openid-with-your-existing-asp-net-application-using-universal-providers.aspx and might provide a better step-by-step.

In particular, notice the NuGet packages at the beginning of the tutorial. In addition to getting the necessary .dll assemblies for things to work, NuGet packages often make changes to the `Web.Config` file, which is where I would expect to find endpoint information for your Oauth provider. If you didn't install all of those packages, you may be missing some configuration settings.

I don't have the specific project templates you're talking about so I can't check: can you post your web.config? There might be something there that needs tweaking.

Oh, and there's also a tutorial on writing your own Google provider, which seems quite straightforward:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/23/plugging-custom-oauth-openid-providers.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the info.  The template is built into VS2012 express for web.  Seriously all I'm doing after installing VS2012 express for web, is creating a new MVC4 C# project - internet application - then uncommenting that one line!

Comment: I read that first article before. I'm not really interested in writing custom code though.  I just want to know how to get the stock template to work, I imagine it's an environment type issue, maybe our corporate proxy server or the fact that I'm running it as local host.

Comment: Fair enough. As a .net programmer, it would be my instinct to look in web.config for a missing endpoint issue. Endpoints are just the addressing configuration for .net services (and open auth is just another service). While you can configure them in code, the MS way is normally to do it in a .config file. But not having the templates you have here to test, I can't confirm this. Good luck - I hope you find a solution.

Comment: @LDMediaServices: OAuth/Openid templates don't have endpoint configurations in .config, because (I assume it) they're done programmatically inside assemblies like in DotNetOpenAuth.* eighter in Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth. I suspect it's a proxy issue (doens't seem firewall) and I don't know if there are an easy workaround to that.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues with OAuth providers on localhost, not ure if this is acctually the reason for your issue, but if I'm doing any OAuth stuff I always make sure I'm running on port 80 and add a line for:

```
127.0.0.1     www.local.com
```

to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` (you need to open in notepad as administrator),
Then instead of going to `http://localhost:1234` just go to `http://www.local.com` and give that a try.  It may not fix the issue, but rules out one more thing,
hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately it didn't help, but maybe others will find it useful in future.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having this problem at your office only, then proxy might be the issue. Adding proxy autodetection configuration to your project's `Web.config` file should do the trick:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.net>
   <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="True">
    <proxy autoDetect="True" usesystemdefault="True" />
   </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```